# How to store data to array and SUM data from Array

Tags: java, android

I have radio button in radiogroup, which is if i click it i'll get the value and show it as a Toast Message, and then i want to store the value into Array.

Here is my code.

This code has function to get value to text of radiobutton.

```java
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(i);
                String text = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```

After i get the value in Array, i want to sum the data in new variable.

Comment: I find your question unclear. You extract a single string here. Is that a number? Or a string containing multiple numbers like "1 2 3" .... in other words: what exactly do you retrieve, and how exactly do you want it to be stored? ( and note: you really only need a search engine to learn how to compute the sum of elements of an array of numbers ... dont ask others for something so basic, search the answer yourself, that is how you learn programming)

Comment: sorry, how to change it to number?

Comment: Same story: there are zillions of books, tutorials or Q/As here on SO that tell you that thing. Seriously: it seems that "asking others" is your first impulse to solve (very basic) problems. Try to change your mode of operation. Use a search engine **first**. Get a good book on Java basics, and work through that. Asking for explanations should be your *last resort*, not your first option. You learn programming by trying to solve things yourself. And as said: such things are well documented. Why do you expect us to write down for you ...what was written down so many times before?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a list outside of the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and every time you click the radio button add that element to the list:

ArrayList mArrayList = new ArrayList();

mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(i);
            String text = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();
            mArrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(text));
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

And than when you want to get the sum of the list:

If you are using java 8:

`int sum = mArrayList .stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();`

if not:

```
int sum = 0;

for(Integer iterator: mArrayList){  
  sum+=iterator
 }
```

//after that your sum is ready

That's all

**Edit**

Just make sure that all radio buttons are Numbers. If you face empty number or a character your Android app will crash giving a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: and then how to check if data has stored in array?

Comment: you can check `if (mArrayList.size() > 0)`

Comment: @asyiqc Honestly: by approaching things in a different order. Learn a bit about java basics before trying to do the complex stuff with android. You could have other code that checks if that list is empty or not.

Comment: can i check with logd??

Comment: @asyiqc No you cant. That is a facility to **log** strings. That has **nothing** to do you with your app storing information in fields.

Comment: after you have stored the sum in the arraylist you can check the sum: 

`Log.d("Some Tag", String.valueOf(mArrayList.size()))`

Comment: the value remains 1, not automatically add

Answer (score 0):

To store the values in an array, use **ArrayList**

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Every time you want to store an int value, use:

```
myList.add(the int value);
```

In your case, substitute the int value with `Integer.parseInt(text)`

For the summing process: iterate the array with a simple for as follows

```
int total = 0;

for (int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){
    total += myList.get(i);
}
```